# Number (with all digits different and ordered in increasing order) multiplied by 9 has the sum of its digits equal to 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Bob tells his sister that if she thinks of a number with all its digits different and ordered in increasing order from left to right, and then multiplies the number she thought of by 9, he always knows how much the sum of the digits of the result of multiplication, although he does not know what number his sister thought.
> Decide if Bob is lying or telling the truth and explain why.
> Note: she thinks of a non-zero number.

The only useful thing that I found is that $9N=10N-N$, thus $9N=\overline{a_1(a_2-a_1)(a_3-a_2)\cdots (a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})(a_n-a_{n-1}-1)(10-a_n)}$, if $N=\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Is the sister allowed to think of $0$?

Comment: No, she is not allowed to think of 0 (in any case, the 0 only could go in front of the number, and thus it would not change the number)

Comment: @Qqq, the question was not whether numbers like $0358$ are allowed; the question was whether the number $0$ is allowed. And it is a pertinent one, because if is _is_ allowed, then Bob is lying. You should edit your question to explicitly forbid the number $0$ ("if she thinks of a _non-zero_ number...").

Comment: I was surprised by this! It seems to hold for all non-zero numbers, but I can't find a slick proof.

Comment: The question is confusing.  What information does Bob have after multiplication by 9?  The result?  If so, Bob divides by 9.  If not, what?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Bob not trying to guess the original number.  Bob is predicting what the result of multiplying the number by $9$ and adding the digits will be.  Presumably you we always get the same result.  (And presumably that result is $9$.  It is if the original number is $1$ or if the original number is $1357$... Presumably if Bob can guess it can't ever not be $9$.)

Comment: The sum of the digits of any multiple of $9$ is a multiple of $9$.  So Bob knows the result will be a multiple of $9$.  But I can he know it won't be $18$ or $27$ or something else?  Ex.  If she's thinking $103$ then $103\times 9 = 927$ and $9+2+7=18$.  But the digits of $103$ are not in order.   Apparently putting the digits in order rules out higher multiples of $9$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $9n=10n-n$ is a good start.  The idea then is to note that, since the digits are strictly increasing, it is easy to see how that subtraction must turn out.  Indeed, in most places you are subtracting a number from one which is strictly greater. More precisely, other than in the units and the tens place we are subtracting $a_i$ from $a_{i+1}$, thereby producing the gap between $a_{i+1}$ and $a_i$. (using your notation) In the units place we are, of course, subtracting the final digit from $0$ which will require a simple carry.

Consider the gap sequence, pretending that the number begins with a $0$.  Thus, if your starting number were $24578$ the gap sequence would be $\{2,2,1,2,1\}$.  We remark that the partial sums of the gaps return the original digits.  In particular, the sum of all the gaps is the final digit...let's call it $d$.

Then the digits in $9n=10n-n$ are precisely the digits in the gap sequence, save that the final one is lowered by $1$ and we append $10-d$.  All that remains is to remark that the sum of the digits in that string is precisely $d-1+10-d=9$ and we are done.

Example:  sticking with $n=24578$ we get $9n=221202$ as claimed.

Remark:  the lowering of the penultimate gap and the appending of $10-d$ are the result of the obvious carry, when you try to subtract $d$ from $0$.  Of course, if $n=0$ at the start, then there is no carry.  In all other cases, there is always a carry at that stage (and no other).

Comment: In general any positive number divisible by 9 has this property, although you may need to repeat sum. Example $639 \to 18 \to  9.$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg   Not seeing your point.  Yes, of course the digit sum of $9n$ is divisible by $9$.  The point is to show that, in this particular case, it is exactly $9$.

Comment: " although you may need to repeat sum" But Bob is guessing the *exact* sum *without* any repeat.  That's the rub. Showing that if the digits are in increasing order (which $73$ is not) then to sum of the digits *WITHOUT* repeating will be $9$.  Not a multiple of $9$ but $9$ exactly.

Comment: @fleablood  I think you might have meant to address this to herb steinberg, who was commenting on my post.

Comment: " I think you might have meant to address this to herb steinberg, who was commenting on my post."  Yes.... I was directly addressing that to herb steinberg (whom I quoted directly)

Answer (score 0):

> $9N=\overline{a_1(a_2-a_1)(a_3-a_2)\cdots (a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})(a_n-a_{n-1}-1)(10-a_n)}$

And that's it!

$a_1 + (a_2-a_1) + (a_3 -a_2) \cdots (a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}) + (a_n-a_{n-1}-1) + (10-a_n)=$
$ (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ..... + a_n) - (a_1 + a_2 + ...a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+a_n) + (-1+10) =$
$ 9$.

Always.

The only real issue is are these the *actual* digits of $9N$?  And so long as 1) $a_n \ne 0$ and 2) $a_n- a_{n-1} \ge 1$ and 3) we always have $a_k > a_{k-1}$-- then those will be the digits.  If those are not the case then there will be some more borrowing involved in settling out the digits and those won't be the digits.

And that is why the condition that the digits are increasing order was stipulated. This assure those three conditions.

.....

(note if they are not increasing, say $n = 31$ then $9\times 31 = 10\times 30 -30 + 10 - 1 = 3\times 10^2 + (1-3 -1)\times 10 + (10-1)$ all right, but $\overline{a_1(a_2-a_1 -1)(10 -a_1)} = \overline{3(-3)9}$ isn't a legitimate number as  we don't have $(a_2 - a_1) \ge 1$. so instead we have $9N = \overline{(a_1-1)(10 + a_2 -a_1-1)(10-a_2)}$ and the sum of the digits is $(a_1 + a_2) -(a_1+a_2) +(-1 +10 -1 + 10) = 18$.)

(Also note we don't need them distinct and increasing.  If they repeat it's okay so long as they never decrease and the last digit is always higher than the second to last.)

====OLD ANSWER BELOW ======

If the original number is $N= d_k 10^k + d_{k-1} 10^{k-1} + ...... +d_210^2 + d_110 + d_0$ (a $k+1$ digit number) then

$9N = 9d_k 10^k + 9d_{k-1} 10^{k-1} + ...... +9d_210^2 + 9d_110+9d_0=$

$(10-1)d_k10^k + (10-1)d_{k-1} 10^{k-1} + ...... +(10-1)d_2 10^2 + (10-1)d_110 + (10-1)d_0=$

$d_k10^{k-1} + (d_{k-1}-d_k)10^k+ (d_{k-2} - d_{k-1})10^{k-1} + ..... + (d_1-d_2)10^2 +(d_0-d_1)10 -d_0$.

Now here's the kicker.  The digits are distinct and in increasing order (that is $d_k < d_{k-1} < ...< d_2 < d_1 < d_0$). So each of the $9>d_{m}-d_{m-1} \ge 1$ and is therefore a single digit in itself.  Except for the very last $-d_0$.  But we can "borrow" a $10$ for $(d_0 - d_1)10$ as $d_0 - d_1 \ge 1$.

So

$9N = d_k10^{k-1} + (d_{k-1}-d_k)10^k+ (d_{k-2} - d_{k-1})10^{k-1} + ..... + (d_1-d_2)10^2 +(d_0-d_1-1)10+ (10 -d_0)$

And that is a $k+2$ digit number with the digits: $d_k, (d_{k-1}-d_k),(d_{k-2} - d_{k-1}),(d_1-d_2),(d_0-d_1-1),$ and $(10-d_0)$.

So if we add up all the digits we get $d_k+ (d_{k-1}-d_k)+(d_{k-2} - d_{k-1})+(d_1-d_2)+(d_0-d_1-1)+(10-d_0)=9$.

(If the numbers weren't distinct and increasing we couldn't assure the sums of the digits would collapse so nicely.  The "rule of $9$" assures the sum of the digits will be a multiple of $9$ but the strictly increasing nature of the digits assures a "single shift" and we can't get a higher multiple of $9$. Ex. $9\times 103 = 927$ and problem is the "shift" $(10-1)1\times 100 + (10-1)0\times 10 + (10-1)3 = 1\times 1000 + (0-1)100 + (3-0)10 -3=1\times 100 + (-1)100 + (2)10 + 7$ doesn't shift cleanly.)

(I suppose I should do the case where $k =0$  $N$ is a *one* digit number.  But that's eas.  $9\times d_0 = 10d_0 - d_0 = (d_0-1)10 + (10 -d_0)$ and the sum of the digits is $(d_0 -1)+(10-d_0) = 9$.)